# Почему перестала срабатывать кнопка «купить» у товара на opencart?

Tags: javascript, opencart

Устанавливаю свою вёрстку на opencart. Потихоньку меняю дефолтный шаблон в header.tpl. Изначально кнопка "купить" работала, но в какой-то момент перестала, не успел заметить из-за чего. В консоли пишет:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
>   at Object.add (common.js:151)
>   at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.php?route=common/home:319)

Сама кнопка такая:

```
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('40');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Купить</span></button>
```

В common.js на строке 151:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
  type: 'post',
  data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
  },
  success: function(json) {
    $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

    if (json['redirect']) {
      location = json['redirect'];
    }

    if (json['success']) {
      $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

      // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
      }, 100);

      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

      $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: покажите строки, на которые указывает парсер ошибок. И вы используте окмоды какие-нибудь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь вот про этот [header.tpl](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/77041c0e586edcf0e89d4c129611577840c6c6ad/upload/install/view/template/common/header.tpl), то вы, вероятно, удалили подключение `jquery`, а именно вот эту строчку:

```
...

<script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

....
```